# Create Search engine in my Laravel website

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm building a delpdesk web site using laravel and mysql. I will store some informations in my database according to many relational tables. So that I want to allow website users to find details through a search form that accessing Database.

Basically I need to create custom search engine in my laravel website. how can i do it?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look on [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/getting-started.html) or solr for search.

Comment: you can use algolia for free if you have less than 10k records for search.

Comment: Best practice is to use something like elasticsearch or algolia indeed. Or you can create a materialized view which contains the data you want to search and use Laravel Scout for example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout